# What do the different options mean when connecting to a wireless display?

Tags: windows-10, miracast

Whe connected to a wireless display? There is a gear icon with a few different options

- Gaming
- Working
- Watching videos

[image: sscreenshot]

What do they mean? I noticed no visual changes upon going through the various options.

Comment: There was no tag, but I think there should be one for [wireless-display]. There are a [handful](https://superuser.com/search?q=wireless+display) of questions matching.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the icons/menu depend on the make and model of the projector you are connecting to. Try to find that out, and search for the manual on the 'net.